# PHP to JSON on client side

Tags: php, javascript, json, variables

I'm using Rob Monies 'Jquery Week Calendar' to build a calendar application.

I have a MSSQL DB a with table named 'dates' and the following fields:

id
start
end
title

I would like to query this DB in PHP and then pass the results to Javascript, Javascript will then render the events in the browser.

The Javascript needs to receive the event details in JSON format as per the following example:

```
{"id":1,"start": 2010-10-09T13:00:00,"end":2010-10-09T14:00:00,"title":"Lunch with Mike"},
{"id":2,"start": 2010-10-10T13:00:00,"end": 2010-10-10T14:00:00, "title":"Dev Meeting"}
```

So far, to keep things simple I've just returned one row from the DB at a time, however - I will need the application to be able to render multiple events, as stored in the database.

I've tried using `json_encode()` to put the values into a var and pass them to a Javascript var called DB_events - if I return the DB_events in an alert box on the client side I see the following;

```
{"id":1, "start":2010-10-09T13:00:00, "end":2010-10-09T14:00:00,"title":"Lunch with Mike"}
```

which looks ok, but when I do this in my code:

```
events : [DB_events]
```

It doesn't work :(

If I take PHP out of the equation, and just do the following on the client side:

```
var DB_events = {"id":1, "start":2010-10-09T13:00:00, "end":2010-10-09T14:00:00,"title":"Lunch with Mike"};
```

and return DB_events in an alert box, I get:

```
[object] [Object]
```

But when I do this:

```
events : [DB_events]
```

it works!

Back to PHP …

If I put the SQL result into PHP vars as follows:

```
$id = id;
$start = start;
$end = end;
$title = title;
```

and pass those vars to the following JS vars:

```
JS_id
JS_start
JS_end
JS_title
```

and do this on the client side:

```
var DB_events = {"id":JS_id, "start":JS_start, "end":JS_end,"title":JS_title};

events : [DB_events]
```

that also works.

As you can probably tell - I'm new to this and probably missing something very basic.

Any help, advice or information would be very much appreciated :)

Many Thanks

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. when you get a string representation of your object it means that you've exported it as a string not as an object.
2. when you get `[object] [Object]` it means that it is now an object, which is right!

You can do this with **JSONP** if you get JSON from an **URL**:

```
// send the request via <script> tag
var src    = "..."; // url of the JSON output
var head   = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script.setAttribute("src", src); 
head.appendChild(script);
```

Or parse it as a **string** with **JSON parser**:
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

```
var DB_events = JSON.parse( ...JSON output as a string... );
```

Or by directly passing it from PHP with an **inline `<script>` block** in your page:

```
echo "<script>";
echo "var DB_events = " . json_encode( ... ) . ";";
echo "</script>";
```

​

Comment: great, how would you pass this from php to JS on the client side?

Comment: or would this line set the JS variable from PHP?

Comment: That looks great, I'm on UK time so will give it a try first thing in the morning - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you use jsocn decode

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

You can split the  result and make it differenct variables like start ,end , events etc

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php